# ftp client (from apache.org) and socket except

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, apache-commons-net

I use the library from apache.org and use the code from java2s.com:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
    client.login("admin", "secret");
    client.enterLocalPassiveMode();

    String filename = "sitemap.xml";
    fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);

    client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
    fos.close();
    client.disconnect();
  }
}
```

I downloaded the library, moved it to the lib folder and renamed it to cn.jar.

compiling: (under Windows 7)

```
javac -cp ".;lib\cn.jar" Main.java
```

running: (under Windows 7)

```
java -cp ".;lib\cn.jar" Main
```

and I've got: http://freelifer.narod.ru/some.png

How to fix it? What is wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to this server using standalone FTP client? Does issuing `telnet ftp.domain.com 21` or `ftp ftp.domain.com` allow you to interact with the server? It seems like networking problem, your code is fine (except creating `fos` to eraly :-)).

Answer (score 1):

My guess: the FTP protocol defines two connections - a *data connection* and a *control connection*. Your sample code established the control connection successfully:

```
client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
client.login("admin", "secret");
```

The default constructor of `FTPClient` defines that the data connection should be established in active mode (meaning that the server will try to open a connection to your client when you request a file). I think that the data connection cannot be opened due to your firewall or some other network issue. The data connection is opened here:

```
client.retrieveFile("/" + filename, fos);
```

You may try passive mode or you may check your network settings again. Passive mode is entered by calling the `enterLocalPassiveMode` method of FTPClient. This method causes a PASV (or EPSV) command to be issued to the server. Example:

```
client.connect("ftp.domain.com");
client.login("admin", "secret");
client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

Cheers!

Comment: try to call client.enterLocalPassiveMode() please. Before retrieving the file and after client.login("admin", "secret");

Comment: i edited my code but got previous message again ( look at attached image :) )

Comment: Are you completely sure that you added client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
 in your code, then you recompiled your class? Sorry to ask you that but I have the commons.net sources and I can clearly see that this error (on the picture) occurs when you are issuing the PORT command to the server when you work in local active mode?

Comment: http://freelifer.narod.ru/some.png yes, i am stupid. so sorry. ok, i have got new message )

Comment: Heh, no probs. This new message is an indication of a totally different problem. The message is incorrect and misleading though. Not the RECV failed but rather the PASV command failed. The PASV command may fail, for example, in case that your FTP server is behind NAT and does not know its "real" address. What I recommend you is to try passive mode first with a more advanced client software and see if it works.

Comment: How do you obtain `client` in your sample code, if not from the default constructor (which assumes active mode)?